# Is there any C/C++ editor that supports replacing a regular expression

Tags: c++, c, editor

Is there any C/C++ editor that can replace regular expressions. Say for example I want to replace every word that starts with *fool* by *cool*, so I can say replace fool* by cool* and as a result *fool1*, *fool2* and *fool3* will be replaced by *cool1*, *cool2* and *cool3*.

Comment: Visual Studio - but they're a bit retarded - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html

Comment: I would ask which C++ editor cannot replace by regular expressions?

Comment: @ybungalobill, go ahead (I didn't say that to you)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [vim](http://vimregex.com/).

Comment: I tried this answer in the form "I use vim", but you went more creative to fit in "at least 30 chars" :)

Comment: Is there any more user-friendly editor that can do this? Vim is a bit cumbersome to use.

Comment: @unkulunkulu : Finally we both suggesting vim :)

Comment: @MetallicPriest not sure how you say that. Especially in this context - applying a regex substitute is two characters of prefix - a colon and an 's'. Not sure how much user friendlier you can get. Now if you're saying it's not for newbies, that may be true.

Answer (score 6):

Emacs works quite fine for this.

(What is C/C++ and what is an editor for a specific programming language?)

Comment: +1. Phew!, I thought nobody would mention it... I can't think on any other editor so powerful as Emacs when it comes to this king of thing...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by C/C++ editor. Two lightweight solutions are `notepad++` and `vim`.

Comment: I use notepad++, I'll check out this option.

Comment: @kracekumar: would you tell us the reason?

Comment: @yi_H : You can't run notepad++ in GNU/Linux without wine. Solution was not cross platform.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all IDEs/Editors I've worked with have this feature (Visual Studio, Eclipse, EmEditor,...) usually in search/find dialog you have a "Use Regular Expressions" option. also for what you described you don't really need a regex, just replace *foo* with *coo*.

Comment: Well that was just an example :)!

Answer (score 1):

Non-Windows users (and Cygwin users) can also use command-line tools (like grep and sed) to edit their code. You can edit code using sed if you need to mass-replace something.

Visual Studio is a slight bit easier to use though.

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse CDT for small/medium size projects... This works very well on most of C/C++ projects, and gives you many more features than you mentioned as a need...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT has a lot of options to find & replace using regular expressions. Try it. It has also refactoring tools alowing you to rename variables or function names at once in the whole project.